# No data for temp table in nested select

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE #AvailableDate (
    CustomKey INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    SelectedFaceID INT,
    FromDate DATETIME,
    ToDate DATETIME,
    TempDate DATETIME,
    Diff INT)

INSERT INTO #AvailableDate(SelectedFaceID, FromDate, ToDate, TempDate, Diff)
    SELECT
        SelectedFaceID,
        FromDate,
        ToDate,
        (SELECT TOP 1 ToDate FROM #AvailableDate WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY #AvailableDate.CustomKey DESC),
        (SELECT DATEDIFF(
                    d,
                    ToDate,
                    (SELECT TOP 1 ToDate FROM #AvailableDate ORDER BY CustomKey DESC)
                )
        )
    FROM
        SelectedFace WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Here I haven't been getting the value of `SELECT TOP 1 ToDate FROM #AvailableDate WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY #AvailableDate.CustomKey DESC` in above query or any value associated with `#AvailableDate`

Comment: but if the table is empty (you just create it above) then what values would you expect?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE #AvailableDate
(
 CustomKey       INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
 SelectedFaceID  INT,
 FromDate        DATETIME,
 ToDate          DATETIME,
 TempDate        DATETIME,
 Diff            INT
)
INSERT INTO #AvailableDate
  (
    SelectedFaceID,
    FromDate,
    ToDate,
    TempDate
  )
 SELECT 506, '2002-12-01 00:00:00.000', '2003-12-02 00:00:00.000', (SELECT TOP 1 ToDate FROM #AvailableDate ORDER BY CustomKey DESC)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 506, '2003-12-04 00:00:00.000', '2004-12-05 00:00:00.000', (SELECT TOP 1 ToDate FROM #AvailableDate ORDER BY CustomKey DESC)`

But I get it here in this case

Comment: When you say 'but I get it in this case' are you running this select in the same session? E.g. the same window in your SQL Query tool?  The #table_name is a temp table in at least some RDBMSes - you don't say which one you're using. One a temp table is only visible to this one session

Comment: Yeah I am on same session, I am running those query in the same session where temp table are created. The problem is when I have multiple select query than its value displays whereas inserting from other table with the same params it doesn't??
I don't know if I am not getting you guys or I am not able to, either way any hint would be good for me

Comment: Try putting you insert statements (from your comment above) between the CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements and see if it works - this won't be what you want in reality but it might help you debug your problem

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, I just want to have things done during creation but now I will have to do in multiple steps, anyways thanks for your suggestion guys

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a brand-new temp table and expect it to have some values because you are doing a select on that same table you just created. Values will be there only after you populate it.

You can still use temp table, though you will have to re-arrange your batch and first make an insert and later update records with TempDate and Diff fields.